# Apply a filter on a sorted ListCollectionView/ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, filter, listcollectionview

**What I have**

I have a `UserControl` made of a `TextBox` and a `ListBox`. The `ListBox` has its `ItemsSource` bound to an `ObservableCollection` in a `DataContext` via a `ListCollectionView` with a custom sorting and filter as we'll see below. The purpose of the control is to display in the `ListBox` only the items (`string`s) in the source collection that contain the text in the `TextBox`. For that purpose I apply a filter on the `ListCollectionView`.

I have two additional constraints. 1, my original collection is not alphabetically sorted but the items displayed in the `ListBox` are using a `ListCollectionView` `CustomSort`. 2, I must display only the first 5 items (alphabetically sorted) that match the string in the `TextBox`. I apply a filter on the `ListCollectionView` for that.

**Expectation**

Let's say my collection is defined as such in my `DataContext`:

```
this.AllItems = new ObservableCollection<string>
{
    "Banana", 
    "Watermelon",
    "Peach",
    "Grape",
    "Apple",
    "Pineapple",
    "Cherry",
    "Durian",
    "Rambutan",
    "Strawberry",
    "Raspberry",
    "Lemon",
    "Orange",
    "Sugar cane",
    "Guava",
    "Tomato",
    "Coconut",
    "Melon",
    "Äpple",
    "Glaçon",
    "Etape",
    "Étape"
};
```

And in my `TextBox` I input the letter 'e' (all comparisons done are case-insenstive). I expect the `ListBox` to display the following 5 items (`CurrentUICulture` is set to fr-FR):

- Apple
- Äpple
- Cherry
- Etape
- Étape

because they are the first 5 items that contain the letter 'e' when sorted alphabetically. However I get the following items in my application:

- Apple
- Grape
- Peach
- Pineapple
- Watermelon

because they are the first 5 items in my collection that contain the letter 'e' **THEN** sorted alphabetically.

**My code**

Here's the code to understand what I have and my problem.
It should work virtually only using a copy/paste of the below (beware of namespaces and `CurrentUICulture`). I'm using C# 4.0.

1) The `MainWindow`

```
<Window x:Class="MyNamespace.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:FoobarViewModel x:Key="Foobar"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <local:Foobar DataContext="{StaticResource Foobar}" AllItems="{Binding AllItems}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

2) The class used as the `DataContext`

```
public class FoobarViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> allItems;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public FoobarViewModel()
    {
        this.AllItems = new ObservableCollection<string>
        {
            "Banana", 
            "Watermelon",
            "Peach",
            "Grape",
            "Apple",
            "Pineapple",
            "Cherry",
            "Durian",
            "Rambutan",
            "Strawberry",
            "Raspberry",
            "Lemon",
            "Orange",
            "Sugar cane",
            "Guava",
            "Tomato",
            "Coconut",
            "Melon",
            "Äpple",
            "Glaçon",
            "Etape",
            "Étape"
        };
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> AllItems
    {
        get
        {
            return this.allItems;
        }
        set
        {
            this.allItems = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("AllItems");
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

3) The XAML of my `UserControl`

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNamespace.Foobar"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBox x:Name="textbox" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <ListBox x:Name="listbox" Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

4) And finally, most important the code behind of my `UserControl` `Foobar`.

```
public partial class Foobar : UserControl
{
    #region Fields
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AllItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "AllItems",
        typeof(IEnumerable<string>),
        typeof(Foobar),
        new PropertyMetadata(AllItemsChangedCallback));

    private const int MaxItems = 5;
    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    public Foobar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        textbox.KeyUp += TextboxKeyUp;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public IEnumerable<string> AllItems
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable<string>)this.GetValue(AllItemsProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(AllItemsProperty, value); }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Methods
    private void TextboxKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox localTextBox = sender as TextBox;
        if (localTextBox != null)
        {
            var items = ((ListCollectionView)listbox.ItemsSource).SourceCollection;

            if (items.Cast<string>().Any(x => x.ToLower(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture).Contains(localTextBox.Text.ToLower(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture))))
            {
                this.ApplyFilter();
                listbox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                listbox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void AllItemsChangedCallback(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Foobar control = sender as Foobar;
        if (control != null)
        {
            List<string> source = new List<string>((IEnumerable<string>)e.NewValue);

            ListCollectionView view = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(source);
            view.CustomSort = new CustomSort();
            control.listbox.ItemsSource = view;
            control.ApplyFilter();
        }
    }

    private void ApplyFilter()
    {
        ListCollectionView view = (ListCollectionView)listbox.ItemsSource;

        int index = 0;
        view.Filter = x =>
        {
            bool result = x.ToString().ToLower(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture).Contains(textbox.Text.ToLower(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture));
            if (result)
            {
                index++;
            }

            return index <= MaxItems && result;
        };
    }
    #endregion

    private class CustomSort : IComparer
    {
        public int Compare(object x, object y)
        {
            return String.Compare(x.ToString(), y.ToString(), CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase);
        }
    }
}
```

The whole code is working as expected, except the filtering which is done in the `ApplyFilter` method. Basically, this method just checks each and every item in the collection against whatever is in the `TextBox` and provided there is not already more than the maximum number of items returned, the item will be included in the filter. When I debug this method, I can see that items are browsed in the original order of the collection and not in the sorted order althought the filter seem to be done on the `ListCollectionView` and not the `ObservableCollection<string>`.

It seems the filter is applied first, then the sorting. I want the sorting to apply first then the filtering.

**My question**

How can I apply the filter on the sorted `ListCollectionView` and not on the original non-sorted collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create a generic [`IComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx) and use the [`Enumerable.OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, TKey>, IComparer<TKey>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549422.aspx) extension method before you create the collection view.

So you end up with something like:

```
private static void AllItemsChangedCallback(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Foobar control = sender as Foobar;
    if (control != null)
    {
        var newEnumerable = (IEnumerable<string>)e.NewValue;
        var sorted = newEnumerable.OrderBy(s => s, new CustomSort());
        var source = new List<string>(sorted);

        var view = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(source);
        control.listbox.ItemsSource = view;
        control.ApplyFilter();
    }
}

private class CustomSort : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        return String.Compare(x, y, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase);
    }
}
```

Then your collection view is already sorted and filtering can be applied.

Comment: Man, your solution is so simple and yet it works so fine! It's been 3 days I've tried to find out a solution and couldn't come up to anything... Thanks a lot!